# How to check if a Puppeteer Page is currently in navigation state?

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I'm writing some wrapper on top of Puppeteer. I have a general "click" function, and a "getHtml" one:

```
class Page {
    
        ....

    async click(selector: string) {

        await this.context.evaluate((querySelector, text) => {

            const elem = document.querySelector(querySelector) as HTMLInputElement;

            if (elem) {

                elem.click();
            }

        }, selector);
    }

    async getHtml() {//

        const html = await this.context.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelector('html')?.innerHTML;
        })

        return html;
    }
}
```

As you can see, click() function just receives a querySelector , and then clicks whatever element is found.

Problem is, that if this element click causes navigation, **the subsequent operations** might encounter this error:

> Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

For example, if the client code does something like this:

```
const page = new Page(...)
...

await page.click('someSelector')//If this selector matches a link, navigation is triggered.

await page.getHtml()//Then there is an Error
```

Is there any way, to check if there is a pending navigation, so that i could conditionally wait for it, within various functions?

**I cannot just waitForNavigation by default**, within the click function, because this will cause the code to hang, in case there was no navigation caused by the click.

Comment: You could check document.readyState

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, for a simple reason: in order to check document.readyState, i need to call page.evaluate, which throws the error.

Answer (score 3):

### **2 Years Later...**

I landed here because I was getting the `Execution context was destroyed [...]` after calling `page.goto()` and a subsequent `page.content()`.

### **tl;dr**

```js
// dirty hack to avoid blocking of 'page.waitForNavigation()'
await page.waitForSelector('html')
```

`page.waitForSelector('html')` would immediately resolve if there is no subsequent redirects due to setting `location.href` or `History.pushState()` and wait (for one redirect) as soon as the navigation succeeds.

### **- Why this happens?**

In my case it was due to a `location.href` that was set after page was loaded. In this case content was request as the page was being navigated to a new address.

### **- Why not `page.waitForNavigation()`**

`page.waitForNavication()` always blocks until a navigation succeeds. Just like OP, I could not assume that a navigation always happens and I also could not know when it happens beforehand. I wanted to avoid unnecessary blocking so this method was not a viable option.

### **- Shortcomings**

If server responds with anything other than a valid HTML payload, `page.waitForSelector('html')` would block and finally timeout, throwing an error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a workaround like this can help?

```js
const [_, navigation] = await Promise.allSettled([
  elem.click(),
  page.waitForNavigation(),
]);

if (navigation.status === 'fulfilled') /* There was navigation. */;
else /* There was timeout, no navigation. */;
```

Comment: If there's no navigation, `waitForNavigation` would block and is not helpful.